# Chrome devtools: How to call a function from another snippet?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have created many snippets in the Chrome devtool's "Elements > Snippets" panel.

I have a snippet with utility functions like `loadJquery`, `loadUnderscore`, etc. I would like to call these functions from another snippet. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, snippets have no knowledge of other snippets nor is there a way to query them up. Snippets are **isolated** scripts that work independently of each other.

Answer (score 5):

Came here cause I struggle with the same question.

I think the correct answer would be **yes**, *if you run each one of them individually and in dependency order*.

For example, I have a snippet with a `pickDeep()` functionality that I got from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/58279/37955). And then I created some other snippets which use that function. So what I do is just run the one with the `pickDeep()` declaration first, and then any other snippet which use it.

It's the exact same thing as you had typed and run everything on the console directly. So it does not matter where the declaration comes from, as long as it has been declared some way in the current session.

Of course is not the desirable way, but I want to point out there is a workaround.